# ENS Subdomain Ownership/Resolver

Tags: ens

I think this has been answered somewhere in the internet once before, but I can't find the answer anymore. 
If I own DOMAIN.ETH ENS and I create Subdomain.DOMAIN.ETH and transfer the ownership of subdomain to someone else and resolve the address to someone else's address, will I still be able to modify it's settings as the owner of DOMAIN.ETH?

Answer (score 1):

Technically no, but practically yes.

**Technically**

While another account is the owner of a subdomain, you cannot directly manage it. For example, you cannot:

- set a new resolver in ENS
- set the owner of a sub-sub domain
- interact with the public/default resolver on behalf of the subdomain

**Practically**

At any time, you can [reclaim ownership of your subdomain](http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#creating-a-subdomain) by using:

```
ens.setSubnodeOwner(
  namehash('domain.eth'),
  web3.sha3('subdomain'),
  MY_ACCOUNT,
  {from: MY_ACCOUNT}
);
```

Then you can make whatever administrative changes you want. At which point, you can choose to revert ownership back to the previous owner with another `setSubnodeOwner` call.

Comment: is it possible to lock the setSubnodeOwner option so it can't be used anymore?

Comment: @rajohs that is interesting and distinct enough to warrant submitting a new question.